# Why is this slideshow flickering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, slideshow

I have posted a sample jQuery slideshow on my blog here:
robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-slideshow.html

In Chrome, it is flickering on each picture. In IE and Firefox it looks fine, and in the standalone version it seems ok too (even on Chrome):
http://robertmarkbram.appspot.com/content/javascript/jQuery/example_slideshow.html

This is the jQuery in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   // ------
   // ###### Edit these.
   // Assumes you have images in path named 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc.
   var imagePath = "images";  // Relative to this HTML file.
   var lastImage = 5;         // How many images do you have?
   var fadeTime = 4000;       // Time between image fadeouts.
 
   // ------
   // ###### Don't edit beyond this point.
   var index = 1;
   function slideShow() {
      $('#slideShowFront').show();
      $('#slideShowBack').show();
      $('#slideShowFront').fadeOut("slow")
            .attr("src", $("#slideShowBack").attr("src"));
      index = (index == lastImage) ? 1 : index + 1;
      $("#slideShowBack").attr("src", imagePath + "/" + index + ".jpg")
      setTimeout('slideShow()', fadeTime);
   }
 
   $(document).ready(function() {
      slideShow();
   });
</script>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Rob
:)

Comment: Changing show() with css("display", "block") didn't solve the problem either.. 
$('#slideShowFront').css("display", "block");
$('#slideShowBack').css("display", "block");

Comment: Not sure if you fixed it, but it doesn't flicker for me on Chrome 6.0.472.62

Comment: Hi DMan. So strange - I downgraded to 6.0.472.62 and it is flickering, but I have had a friend look at it in Chrome on Linux and it worked ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 possible causes of the flicker.

The first is  from the line `$('#slideShowBack').show();`.

Just remove that line, since it does nothing, since the visibility of `#slideShowBack` is never changed.

The second is when you **[`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** the front image over the back image. Even though the front image is now the same as the back image, it could be causing a momentary flicker.

I would approach the problem slightly differently.

1. Start the HTML page with just one image (this is semantically more meaningful, since the second image is not visible.... you could also start with all the images in the DOM, but that's a different approach).
2. Call the slideshow function for the first time with image #2.
3. Slideshow - Add the new image to the DOM behind the current image
4. Slideshow - Fade the current image revealing the new image behind it.
5. Slideshow - Remove the just faded image from the DOM.
6. Slideshow - After a pause call the slideshow with the next image

I would also enclose all your variables and functions in a self calling anonymous function, so that you don't clutter the global namespace: `(function() { /* Everything in here */ })();`.

The most important change in the code is that I don't suddenly `.show()` an image on top of another image, so there's no possible source of flicker. I also make use of the call back function in **[`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)**. This is just a function that is called after the fade is done:

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="slideShow"> 
   <img src="images/1.jpg" /> 
</div>
```

**The Javascript:**

```
  // Contain all your functionality in a self calling anonymous
  //   function, so that you don't clutter the global namespase.
(function() {
    // ------
    // ###### Edit these.
    // Assumes you have images in path named 1.jpg, 2.jpg etc.
    var imagePath = "images";
    var lastImage = 5;         // How many images do you have?
    var fadeTime = 4000;       // Time between image fadeouts.

    // ------
    // ###### Don't edit beyond this point.
    // No need for outer index var
    function slideShow(index) {          
        var url = imagePath + "/" + index + ".jpg";
          // Add new image behind current image
        $("#slideShow").prepend($("<img/>").attr("src",url));
          // Fade the current image, then in the call back
          //   remove the image and call the next image
        $("#slideShow img:last").fadeOut("slow", function() {
            $(this).remove();
            setTimeout(function() { 
                slideShow((index % lastImage) + 1) 
            }, fadeTime);
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
          // Img 1 is already showing, so we call 2
        setTimeout(function() { slideShow(2) }, fadeTime);
    });
})();
```

### **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrFQh/)** ​

**Calling the next slideshow function:**
Instead of `index = (index == lastImage) ? 1 : index + 1;` you can use the modulus operator `%` to get the remainder from a division, and instead of using a looping variable you have to set outside the `slideShow()` function, just pass which photo you want to show in as an argument... Then you can call the next showImage in your setTimeout with `slideShow(current+1)`. Actually, `slideShow((index % lastImage) + 1)`. It's better to use an anonymous function or a reference with `setTimeout` instead of an eval.

Comment: Hi Peter, I downgraded to Chrome 6.0.472.62 and put your code in this example: http://robertmarkbram.blogspot.com/2010/09/test-slideshow.html. It fades nicely once, then flickers on each subsequent change. Either way, I greatly appreciate the re-write.

Comment: @Robert - The page you link to in your comment is not like the one you have in your OP due to the CSS. The flicker is caused by the translucent outer border. When both images are shown, the two borders overlap, so the edge suddenly becomes darker.You can create a parent DIV to hold the image and only swap the images while keeping the parent DIV unchanged.

Comment: Well, pretty sure I got rid of the border, still seeing the flicker.
http://robertmarkbram.blogspot.com/2010/09/test-slideshow.html

Comment: @Robert - I think the flicker is caused by how you suddenly `.show()` the front image over the back image (though I don't see the flicker myself). I rewrote my answer to avoid this. I just add an image behind the current one... fade the current one and then remove it from the DOM. I think this approach is a little more straight forward too.

Comment: YES!! Magnificent work @Peter - thank you very much! This works nicely in my Chrome without flickering. http://robertmarkbram.blogspot.com/2010/09/test-slideshow.html
Now to add the borders back and see what happens..

Comment: Sweet, when I add the fancy borders back, it doesn't flicker; it barely *pulses* instead (an effect which in an of itself is actually quite cool). Then I moved the border effect to the enclosing DIV and all flickering and pulsing goes away.

I have achieved jQuery zen. :D

Comment: Here is my blog post outlining this: http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-slideshow.html

Comment: @Robert - Nice post. Thanks for the mention ;)